# Rails Docker-compose and existing nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a running server with nginx and with some multiple personal apps. I want to add my new app which is built on docker with docker-compose. Now i want to add it in the existing nginx(which is not built in docker) but not sure how.

current docker-compose.prod file

```
version: '1'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: "sh scripts/wait-for 127.0.0.1:3306 -- scripts/start.sh"
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=production
      - RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true # NOTE: this is for LOCAL PROD. to be removed on the actual server; nginx should handle static assets
      - MYSQL_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    env_file:
      - .env.prod
    ports:
      - "3051:3000" # random port
```

I'm a beginner in both nginx and docker. Could you give out some basic steps on how to configure it to run with nginx

Comment: What's not working?  The `command:` might conflict with what's in the Dockerfile, and `network_mode: host` is an unusual setup that disables Docker features like `ports:` and inter-container communication, so I'd delete those.  But otherwise, once you've got this working, you've got an HTTP service on your host on port 3051, and you'd connect nginx to it the same way as anything else.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, things could quite get busy here. the `command` script is just there to check if the DB port exists before starting. For the `network_mode`, i believe its there because I wanted to use the existing local database. It would not get access to it unless I add the network_mode